# How can I get subsets for multiple data frames at same time?

Tags: r

I have 100 data sets about data for 100 different locations.

I want to get the subset of the same variables for each data set. Something like:

```
dataset1<-subset(dataset1, which(gender=='F'))
dataset2<-subset(dataset2, which(gender=='F'))
dataset3<-subset(dataset3, which(gender=='F'))
dataset4<-subset(dataset4, which(gender=='F'))
```

.....

How can I get all 100 data sets done at the same time instead of writing 100 lines?

Comment: Assuming the datasets are derived from many files with the same structure, I would suggest reading the files into one dataframe, with a column to indicate the file. See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once), for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the dataset in a list and then use `subset` on each using `lapply`

```
list_df <- lapply(mget(paste0('dataset', 1:100)),function(x) subset(x, gender=='F'))
```

It is better to keep data in a list but if needed as separate dataframes, we can use `list2env`

```
list2env(list_df,.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
list_df  <- mget(str_c("dataset", 1:100)) %>%
                   map(~ .x %>%
                               filter(gender == "F"))
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```